# Why are there two different methods to solving this cubic problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem I am going to share is quite simple (it's 12th grade math) but there are two different answers in using two different methods! Could someone verify either one with their expertise, since I haven't got a clue?

The question asks to find the the dimensions of a cylinder such that the volume is exactly 825π cm cubed.

Here's the formula: $V(x)=8πx^3+17πx^2+10πx+π$

The first method is quite simple. If we factor the function above by taking out pi, we get $V(x)=π(x+1)^2(8x+1)$ and since this is the same thing as the volume of a cylinder, where $V=πr^2h$, we can say that the radius = x+1 and the height is 8x+1. To find x, we can simply find the "zero," and in this case the zero is 4. So the radius is just 5 cm and the height is 33 cm.

But the second method is even simpler. All we do is set the volume equal to 825π, and we can factor the whole thing to get $π(x-4)(8x^2+49x+206)$.

Here it's kind of confusing as to what's the radius and what's the height. But the radius, intuitively, is less than the height, so it has to be 4.

But if the radius is 4, then the height must be $h = V/πr^2 = 825 / 16$

Both these answers *work*, but which one is *right*?

Comment: Where did you get the formula $$V(x)=8πx^3+17πx^2+10πx+π$$ ??!? It seems like some context is missing. Is the picture labeled somehow?

Comment: The problem can't be answered as stated -- what does $x$ have to do with the dimensions of the cylinder? Without knowing that, you can't answer.

Comment: If an answer works, how can it be wrong?  How do you say "there is **only** one answer" when you've clearly found 2?

Comment: Saying "the zero is $4$" and we can factor out $(x-4)$ are equivalent statements

Comment: (Answering a comment left as a question...) You are not "substituting the volume at different points". One approach you took was to factor - which is not trivial for most high school students, and then compare this with the given picture. That's called "... by inspection". Then,  **SOMEHOW** you concluded that $$x = 4$$ Then you did the standard approach - (1) write the formula, (2) substitute given info, (3) solve

Answer (score 1):

Consider the problem $x^2=1$.  It is much simpler.  We want to solve for $x$.

Interestingly, $x=1$ works.

So does $x=-1$.

But which one is the *right* answer?

> You need more context to define *right* from *wrong*, but if an answer works and makes sense within context i.e. the height is not negative or imaginary or anything silly like that, then that answer is **one** right answer.  The amount of *right* answers varies from problem to problem.

Comment: Right. The first solution is found "by inspection", which is what OP did. I'm not helping them out further until some context is shown, though!

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Agreed.  IMO the problem wants to find the general form for the height/radius that satisfies the problem, but there may be more context.